# how to orbit or Angularvelocity andengine?

Tags: andengine

I'm working on a project using Andengine GLES2-Anchorcenter

I have a dynamic body and I want to make it move around a circle like earth moving around the sun !
the problem with angular velocity that it rotates around it's center , I want to rotate it around the center of the circle ?
I tried many ways , I tried joints and more but It didn't work 
can anyone help !

Answer (score 0):

Move the body along the (circular) path using setVelocity so that every step the body moves further on the path. (You have to calculate the needed velocity to reach a certain point). It's actually quite easy: sqrt((destination.x - position.x)^2 + (destination.y - position.y)^2) / timestep. You should avoid using setTransform which will break the physical behaviour... Any luck?